# Set Custom PeoplePicker

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, forms-authentication, people-picker

I want to create custom people picker and want to replace default people picker. My requirement is to set different OU for different Tenants with FBA. Default people picker shows all users from OU specified in web.config. But I want to set different OU for different Tenant.

I've tried out following links:
http://sjoere.blogspot.in/2010/01/custom-peoplepicker-with-security.html
http://www.sharepointmint.com/2013/05/creating-custom-sharepoint-people.html

But it is not helpful for me.
Can any one suggest me how can I achieve it?